# How to calculate the slope with isolines/raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-9.3, slope, error-010067

I'm trying to calculate the slope (in %) in ArcGis 9.3, but don't remember how it works.

I already did it some time ago, but this time it doesn't work... I used a shapefile with Isolines (see picture).. [image: My Input Shapefile with the Isolines] This is how i did it the first time :

1. Spatial Analyst Tools -> Interpolation -> From Topo to Raster

   I use my Shapefile and under "Field" i select "Altitude", and under "Outpull cell size"  i chose 5.
     All the other settings i don't change.
2. With my Output Raster : Spatial Analyst Tools -> Surface -> Slope (i select "Percent")
3. With this Output Raster : Spatial Analyst Tools -> Reclass -> Reclassify

My question: is this the right way to calculated the slope?

The problem is that i can't do it this way this time. When i try to do the first step "From Topo to Raster", i have an ERROR message (ERROR 010067).

I hope you guys can help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: Your workflow looks correct. A common problem is when you have coordinate system in degrees and elevation in meters.

Answer (score 1):

Common pitfalls in using Topo to Raster which result in error based on my experience are following 
Selecting improper Feature Type of the feature layer (the layer which you are using to generate raster). For example if the layer is a point layer but you are selecting Field type as contour and vice versa. Please check this in your case. 
Consider changing the “Output cell size” option. We normally tend to make a small output cell size with a view to get a detailed raster but sometimes that value is not feasible considering the coarseness of input data. Changing it to a little higher (even increasing by adding 1) may solves the problem. 
Hope this works

Comment: By the way your question is too broad and improper Heading. You may be interested to get the slope later but first step is to complete the Topo to Raster process without error. I answered your question keeping this in mind. Once you generate a raster then you can ask getting the slop in another question, maybe.